# Check if the list of emails I have are correct or not

Tags: c#, sql, email, email-verification

What exactly i am talking here is not about **regex**, what i want is to filter those email list which i have and find out which emails actually exists and which are faux. And later i can save the list of good one's into the database and rest can delete them.

A piece of code would be fine, but if anybody can tell me about the free software that can do this work for me would be much better. Please help!!!!

Comment: Notice that, as the duplicate explains, 90% of the mail servers out there don't tell you if an email address exists or not and for a good reason (SPAM)

Comment: You can validate the domain (MX lookup), but you cannot accurately test the username.  Thank spammers for that.